# How to get margins on dynamically inserted page breaks within a figure of a tex4ht ebook

Tags: tex4ht, ebook, css

## Summary

I'm creating an ebook using LaTeX and tex4ht. I have certain text that I want to treat as a figure. Sometimes, this text spans multiple pages. When that happens, the dynamically inserted page breaks from the ebook viewer break up the text without regard to any margins (at least, I cannot figure out how to control it). In other words, the page break can happen right in the vertical center of a line of text.

Here is an example of such a line from my MWE below.

[image: Example partial line resulting from dynamic page break]

I've tried adding different margins and paddings in the CSS, but nothing has worked. How can I prevent this from happening?

I'm using Calibre's ebook-convert to create the ebook, but I've experimented with multiple creation programs, multiple formats, and multiple ebook viewers -- everything I've tried behaves similarly with respect to this problem.

## MWE

### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[ebook]{book}

%% Do-nothing environments that provide CSS hooks
\newenvironment{wrap-html-outer}{}{}
\newenvironment{wrap-html-inner}{}{}

\newenvironment{textfigure}{%
  \begin{figure}%
  \begin{wrap-html-outer}%
  \begin{wrap-html-inner}%
}
{
  \end{wrap-html-inner}%
  \end{wrap-html-outer}%
  \end{figure}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

Some text before the figure.

\begin{textfigure}%
\lipsum
\end{textfigure}

Some text after the figure.

\end{document}
```

### tex4ht.cfg

```
\RequirePackage{include4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml}

\AddCss{custom.css}
\ConfigureEnv{wrap-html-outer}{\HCode{<div class="wrap-html-outer">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{wrap-html-inner}{\HCode{<div class="wrap-html-inner">}}{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

### custom.css

```
p.noindent {
    text-indent: 0;
}

div.figure {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

div.wrap-html-outer {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}

div.wrap-html-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

### Commands

```
% htxelatex mwe "tex4ht.cfg,xhtml,charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8" ""
% /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert mwe.html mwe.epub --extra-css custom.css
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but have you tried `tex4ebook`? It is frontend for TeX4ht that can produce Epub files directly. Now, to your actual question, in what viewer this happens? Does it also happen with regular text? I would say that it is an error in the viewer.

Comment: I've experimented a bit with tex4ebook before. But, this is part of a large project, and, at the time, I wasn't able to get tex4ebook to do everything I needed. It's possible it's just because I haven't invested enough time with it. So, basically, I've been sticking with the solution I have that's working.

Comment: I've seen the problem with ebook-viewer (Calibre) and Books (from Mac); I'm pretty sure I've seen it with some other viewers as well.  It does *not* happen with regular text. I think there's something about the handling of the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Calibre is broken on my system due to some Python library clashes. But I can confirm this issue in Foliate, which is Ebook viewer for Gnome.

One issue I can see is that the whole contents of your text float are enclosed in the `<p>` element, which is invalid HTML. In general, you need to close paragraphs before you insert block level elements such as `<div>`. It can be done using the following commands:

```
\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP
```

This needs to be done before each `\HCode{<div ...>}`. You can then require new paragraph using `\par`. The updated configuration file can look like this:

```
\RequirePackage{include4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml}

\AddCss{custom.css}
\def\closecurrentpar{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP}
\ConfigureEnv{wrap-html-outer}{\closecurrentpar\HCode{<div class="wrap-html-outer">}\par}{\closecurrentpar\HCode{</div>}}{}{}
\ConfigureEnv{wrap-html-inner}{\closecurrentpar\HCode{<div class="wrap-html-inner">}\par}\closecurrentpar{\HCode{</div>}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This doesn't fix the real problem though. It seems that it is caused by this declaration in your CSS:

```
div.wrap-html-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
}
```

When you remove `display: inline-block;`, the lines are displayed correctly. What is the purpose of this declaration?

Comment: Great! Honestly, I added `display: inline-block;` quite a while ago after researching how to get centered, left-aligned text. I thought it was necessary, but it looks like it's not and it, as you point out, is causing the problem. I'll remove it. Thanks!